# Wordpress contact form recaptcha

Tags: wordpress

на contact form 7 интегрирую recaptcha, все стандартно

и в один прекрасный момент она начинает подвисать

вот с таким сообщение в консоли:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'secret' of null
    at a.wp.receiveEmbedMessage (wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.9.8:1)
    a.wp.receiveEmbedMessage @ wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.9.8:1
    free.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of null
    at window.onmessage (free.js:31)
```

плагин переустанавливал, ключи тоже

Answer (score 0):

Перезагрузите reCaptcha, используя функцию `grecaptcha.reset ();` в JS.
Или используйте Fancy box плагин.